# Implode in Reverse Order in PHP with out using array_reverse

Tags: php, implode

How do you implode the array to string in reverse order, but without using array_reverse?

eg:

```
$arrayValue = array(test1, test2, test5, test3);
```

I would like to implode the above array and get the output as,

test3,test5,test2,test1

Comment: Uhm... why without `array_reverse()`? It's the perfect tool.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$arrayValue = array(test1, test2, test5, test3);
$imploded_array = implode( ',', array_reverse($array_value));
```

Alright, without array_reverse:

```
$imploded_array = '';
for( $i=0; $i<count( $arrayValue ); $i++ ) {
     $imploded_array .= $arrayValue[count( $arrayValue ) - $i];
     if( $i != count( $arrayValue ) ) $imploded_array .= ', ';
}
```

Comment: OP said without using array_reverse, though that is a strange requirement.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Kind of sneaky to put that information only in the title.

Comment: Thanks, I was in a hurry to correct my first mistake. An evil cycle. And for the record I like your solution more than mine, very neat with substr at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '';
while (($e = array_pop($arrayValue)) !== null)
  $str .= $e.',';
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

But

```
implode(',', array_reverse($arrayValue))
```

is better in every way.